# R assign values to a vector

Tags: r

Can someone explain the example below? So I was trying to calculate andy's weight loss. However, I had a typo on line 2 when assigning the ending weight. So on line 6 I reassigned the ending value to andy_loss. I thought once I do that, then andy_loss vector will update its value automatically, but it didn't. I guess if andy_loss is a function, it would update itself? But Can someone explain to me fundamentally how a computer stores and returns the values under R environment?

thanks.

```
> andy_start <- andy[1,"Weight"]
> andy_end <- andy[1,"Weight"]
> andy_loss<- andy_start - andy_end
> andy_loss
[1] 0
> andy_end <- andy[30,"Weight"]
> andy_loss
[1] 0
> andy_loss<- andy_start - andy_end
> andy_loss
[1] 5
```

Comment: You are using `andy_loss` as a variable, so it stores the value. If you would like `andy_loss` to _recalculate_ the difference each time it is called, you could define it as a function, e.g. `andy_loss <- function() andy_start - andy_end` and then use `andy_loss()` where you need the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the variables which store the data andy_start and andy_end are not dynamically linked. They can be thought of as separate stores for data that you have to update one at a time. When you do andy_start-andy_end you create a new vector that stores the result.None of these items are dynamically linked.

If you had something like this set up in a spreadsheet or a database they results would probably be dynamically linked so if you updated andy_end it would flow through to andy_loss. That is a key difference between a relational database and a static data store such as a text file.

Comment: Wow, nice job figuring out what the question was!